# Angular - UI Bootstrap Datepicker not displaying over Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an Angular app that I am using UI Bootstrap.  I have a modal with a Datepicker at the bottom of the modal.  When expand the Datepicker, it stays inside the modal.  I have tried changed the `z-index`, but that does not change anything.  Here is my `html` for the Datepicker:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Birth Date:</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="form-horizontal" ng-controller="DatepickerCtrl">
      <input name="birthdate" class="input-thick" type="text" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" ng-model="model.dateOfBirth" is-open="opened" min="minDate" max="'2013-11-11'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" required />
      <button class="btn" ng-click="open()"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>
      <p ng-show="!addPatientForm.birthdate.$valid && formSubmitted" class="form-error"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle "></i> <b>Date of Birth: </b>Enter a date in the format MM/DD/YYYY. It cannot be a future date.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the `js`:

```
App.controller('DatepickerCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $modal, $timeout) {
  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };

  $scope.today();

  $scope.showWeeks = true;

  $scope.toggleWeeks = function () {
    $scope.showWeeks = ! $scope.showWeeks;
  };

  $scope.clear = function () {
    $scope.dt = null;
  };

  $scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.minDate = ( $scope.minDate ) ? null : new Date();
  };

  $scope.open = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.opened = true;
    });
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    'year-format': 'yy',
    'starting-day': 1
  };
});
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/pL3YqViXIszxzdjalfB0?p=preview) is a plunker to show my issue.  What do I need to do to make my Datepicker show up correctly?

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle ? Also, I'd recommend using Angular Strap directives for bootstrap ui elements, they worked much better for me. 
[AngulatStrap: datepicker](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/datepicker)

Comment: I added a plunker to show the problem.

Comment: @Ulugbek I wonder how pure Bootstrap CSS issue is related to a JavaScript integration library (strap or angular-ui/bootstrap)....

Comment: It isnt, I just thought it was related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the style `overflow-y: auto` from `.modal-body` fixes the issue. Right now, the overflow-y attribute automatically adds the scrollbar when the content overflows (in this case, the datepicker) rather than allowing it to overflow outside of the modal-body.

Answer (score -1):

@Jakemmarsh's answer is basically right ! !
But in my practice, I use angular-strap and put datepicker in modal, and the problem similar with repaint happened.
I finally solved it by:

```
.modal-open .modal.repaint{overflow-y: hidden !important;}
```

and

```
$("body").delegate("[bs-datepicker]","click",function(){
    $(".modal-open .modal").addClass("repaint");
});
```

May this will helpful for someone. :/

Comment: you should avoid using jquery as small hacks.

Comment: I have to use js because **repaint** happened when modal appear